# Sending raw packets over WiFi on Linux (C/C++)

Tags: c, linux, networking, wifi

I would like to experiment with software in C/C++ to send *raw* 802.11 packets from my WiFi (potentially being able to change the MAC address and so on).

Basically I would like to implement something *very similar* as [this ethernet sample code](https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/) but indeed over WiFi instead of being over Ethernet.

Where should I start? Is there any documentation/examples you can point me to?

Thanks!

Ps. An interesting library which lets you do WiFi scanning is [here](https://github.com/bmegli/wifi-scan)

Comment: wow, believe me you don't want do that

Comment: @Stargateur Why not? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Because it's will be incredible hard. WIFI specification are a nightmare and not every constructor follow standard. There is a reason why WIFI tool never work at 100%. I don't think that there are a lot of people who can help you to do this.

Comment: @Stargateur Exactly my point - If I was able to access a *fd* and then write on it as a socket, that would suffice... was hoping for Linux to provide such abstraction as per my link w.r.t. ethernet.

Comment: This could be the start of some good, interesting questions. But as written, it runs afoul of the site's rules. You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: You should look for [open hardware](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+hardware+wifi). If you were working with Bluetooth rather than Wifi, you could use the [Ubertoooth One](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubertooth+one).

Comment: @jww Appreciate but this is not relevant, I'm interested in *WiFi*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm basically trying to do the same thing, I am trying to send deauthentication packets over wifi with c++. Some of the sources I use are:
[linux raw socket programming](http://the-toffee-project.org/index.php?page=39-videos-linux-raw-socket-programming)

[send 802.11 management frames and data frames using raw sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271119/how-to-send-both-802-11-management-frames-and-data-frames-using-raw-sockets-in-l)

[speed of wifi and management and control frames](https://superuser.com/questions/432498/what-speed-are-wi-fi-management-and-control-frames-sent-at)

[full understanding of 802.11 frame types](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/1447501/Understanding-80211-Frame-Types.htm)

[radiotap headers](https://wifinigel.blogspot.nl/2013/11/what-are-radiotap-headers.html)

[man page for packet7](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html)

[send data over raw ethernet socket using sendto witout sockadrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411851/how-to-send-data-over-a-raw-ethernet-socket-using-sendto-without-using-sockaddr)

I hope this helps and I would really recommend just going to the man page of everything you aren't sure about what it is or does.

And just analyzing packets with Wireshark will also give you a better understanding of how wifi packets work. First, download Wireshark and then start capturing all your data. If you run a tool similar to what you are trying to make (example aircrack-ng). You can see all the packets created and sent. If you just click on the packet you can see the raw bytes and if you hover over them you can see what the bytes stand for and why they are there. If you are trying to create these packets for your self that could be very useful.

And using libtins could also possibly help.

Hope this helps have a nice day!

Comment: There is an answer somewhere here but it is hard to read and pretty weak. Can you clarify?

Comment: what do you mean? How would I clarify my awnser?

Comment: Explain *how* to use these tools and techniques, and why specifically they help.

Comment: is this better already?

Comment: Just barely. It is easier to read, but it still doesn't provide a lot of information. "Use this tool" doesn't help a lot. If someone asked how to get to the Moon, would you respond "Use a spaceship"? Explain *how* and *why*. Why would analyzing packets with WireShark help? Can you show how it could be done in a way useful to the OP?

Comment: Well if you ask me "Where should I start? Is there any documentation/examples you can point me to?" And I provide 7 links related to the matter that does awnser the question right?

Comment: Is this a better explanation why wireshark could be helpfull?